# Trying to use the new Search API of Stripe with metadata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

Currently i'm trying to display some products that are in the Stripe Database. I was trying to do by using if statements, filter and with the new Search API of stripe, but I my mission fail. Some ideia of what could I do?
And Other question, how to I display the feature list of each product?

```
import Router from "next/router";

export default function Product({ prices, category }) {
return (
    <>
        <section className="product__container">
            {prices.map((price, index) => {
                if (price.product.metadata.category === category) {
                    productCard(price, index);
                }
            })}
        </section>
    </>
)}

export function productCard(price, index) {
const amount = price.unit_amount / 100;
return (
    <div key={index} onClick={() => Router.push(`/${price.id}`)}>
        <img src={price.product.images[0]} alt={price.product.name} />
        <p>{price.product.name}</p>
        <small>Feature List</small>
        <p>€{amount.toFixed(2)}</p>
    </div>
);}
```

Comment: You mentioned you tried a lot of different ways to filter Prices, but which one would you prefer to use?  And, for that preferred approach, what did you try and what didn't work?

Also, a Product's Feature List is not currently available in the Stripe API.  The Feature List only shows up on the [Pricing Table](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table).

Comment: I tried to use the "for(const p)", I used the stripe.prices.search {query}, the if statement, foreach, also trying to change the code that connects with the database already doing the query and also the other options but nothing.

Comment: Right, but which method would you ***prefer*** to use?  It's not practical to cover every possible approach, so we should focus on the specific one you ***want*** to use.

Comment: I actually managed to do it somehow, thanks anyway. I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but it was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this, if you have better ways I would appreciate it I am open to new possibilities.

```
import Router from "next/router";

export default function Product({ prices, category }) {
const arr = [];
prices.map((price, index) => {
    if (price.product.metadata.category == category && arr) {
        arr.push(price);
    }
});

return (
    <>
        <section className="product__container">
            {arr.map((price, index) => {
                const amount = price.unit_amount / 100;
                return (
                    <div
                        key={index}
                        onClick={() => Router.push(`/${price.id}`)}
                    >
                        <img
                            src={price.product.images[0]}
                            alt={price.product.name}
                        />
                        <p>{price.product.name}</p>
                        <small>Feature List</small>
                        <p>€{amount.toFixed(2)}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </section>
    </>
);}
```